Where can I find the SSH key fingerprints for KDE Invent?
I wanted to clone a repository from KDE Invent (KDE's GitLab instance) over SSH, however as I did so, I got the warning that their host identification has changed. As such, I wanted to find an authoritative source that could tell me what the Invent SSH key fingerprint is supposed to be, like how GitLab.com has the page SSH host keys fingerprints. However, I've not been able to find a page like that for KDE Invent. The closest I've found is the page Use SSH keys to communicate with GitLab: Verify that you can connect, but the fingerprint there doesn't match what I get, so it's not really helpful.
Where can I find the intended SSH key fingerprints for KDE Invent?

Why the downvote? Is there something wrong with the question?

The various SSH host key fingerprints for KDE Invent can be found at https://invent.kde.org/help/instance_configuration.
